# Return error message if invalid ID, but it still asks for verification even with an IF statement on the function

Tags: javascript

I have 3 arrays, 6 elements each and an ID of 6. Still don't get what is happening. It worked on jsfiddle, but not on the platform I'm using to learn JavaScript:

```
//If the ID is invalid, it should return an error message, like: "Not an valid option".
//If it's valid, should return something like "Neo is a character from Matrix, which was released on theaters in 1999"
// use id = 6

var characters = ["Neo", "Leia", "Harry Potter", "John Wick", "Maui", "Stitch"]
var movies = ["Matrix", "Star Wars", "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone", "John Wick", "Moana", "Lilo & Stitch"]
var releaseDates = ["1999", "1977","2001" ,"2014","2016", "2002"]

    function movie(characters, movies, releaseDates, id){
      if ((id -1) < 0  || characters[id-1] == null || movies[id-1] == null || releaseDates[id-1] == null){
        return "Not an valid option!"
      } 
      return characters[id-1] + " is a character from " + movies[id-1] + " which was released on theaters in " + releaseDates[id-1]  
    }

console.log(movie(characters, movies, releaseDates, 6))
```

The problem is that the platform checker still accuses that **"An invalid ID should return an error message"**, but I think that I did cover it on the IF statement?

Or there's something wrong  with the way I checked for mistakes on the IF statement?

Comment: when `id` is larger than the number of items, the `characters[id-1]` will return `undefined`, not `null`. The same for all your arrays

Comment: so it will ignore the return I set in there? Hmm

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli That said `undefined == null` is `true`

Comment: @SLePort true, it is not the strict equal. Well then, the other thing i see in the example code is that the `movies` function shares the name with the `movies` array.

Comment: Yes, I saw that and fixed. That was a mistake I did copying the arrays to post here. Changed one letter on the example for it to work

Comment: Could you post the full requirements ? Or a link to the actual question ?